# Can I stringify an object in an array during FindIndex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object that contains a few key value pairs, one of which is an array. I am trying to find the index of said array, where the 'options' properties matches the options properties of another object. The function I have attached works properly with just the product ID, but it does not work when trying to compare the options object with the newObj.options.

**The Object**

```
parsedCart = {
  id:1592539903073,
  products: [{
    productID: 1001,
    name: 'Test Product'
    qty: 1,
    options: {
      Color: "Red",
    }
  }]
}
```

**The Object I wish to compare to**

```
newObj = {
  productID: 1001,
  name: 'Test Product',
  qty: 1,
  options: {
    Color: "Red",
  }
}
```

**The Function**

```
function productExists(newObj) {
    return (
      newObj.productID === productID &&
      JSON.stringify(newObj.options) === JSON.stringify(options)
    );
  }

  let exists = parsedCart.products.findIndex(productExists);
  console.log(exists);
```

Comment: In `parsedCart` is missing a `,` next to `'Test Product'`. In `productExists` function where do you get `productID` from?

Comment: I dont actually have parsed cart in my code its dynamically created, so i console logged it and copied the code by sight, so the comma isn't an issue in the actual code. Also, product exists gets the product ID and stuff from the array it is run on, so when I called findIndex on parsedCart.products, for every 'product' object in the array it tests against those conditions in productExists

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to find the index of the products in `parsedCart` according to the data in `newObj`. And created a new items in `parsedCart` options for the example

If i have interpreted your question correctly i think the reason for the error is that you try to use the properties `productID` and `options` in the context of `parsedCart.products` in `findIndex`

Please try the following example

```js
const parsedCart = {
  id: 1592539903073,
  products: [
    {
      productID: 1001,
      name: "Test Product",
      qty: 1,
      options: {
        Color: "Red",
      },
    },
    {
      productID: 1002,
      name: "Test Product",
      qty: 1,
      options: {
        Color: "Red",
      },
    },
  ],
};

const newObj = {
  productID: 1002,
  name: "Test Product",
  qty: 1,
  options: {
    Color: "Red",
  },
};

const index = parsedCart.products.findIndex(
  (product) =>
    newObj.productID === product.productID &&
    newObj.options.Color === product.options.Color
);

console.log(index);
```

Update 0

Compare options using `JSON.stringify()`

```js
const parsedCart = {
  id: 1592539903073,
  products: [
    {
      productID: 1001,
      name: "Test Product",
      qty: 1,
      options: {
        Color: "Red",
      },
    },
    {
      productID: 1002,
      name: "Test Product",
      qty: 1,
      options: {
        Color: "Red",
      },
    },
  ],
};

const newObj = {
  productID: 1002,
  name: "Test Product",
  qty: 1,
  options: {
    Color: "Red",
  },
};

const index = parsedCart.products.findIndex(
  (product) =>
    newObj.productID === product.productID &&
    JSON.stringify(newObj.options) === JSON.stringify(product.options)
);

console.log(index);
```

Comment: this would work if I was using it on an object with known options, the idea is that the options are dynamically found, as different products could have different options. hence I am trying to use options to options and not using the individual keys, as I am dont know what every possible key could be.